Angular (boolean value=isEdit) Value Not Updating in subscribe Callback
I'm encountering an issue with updating a component property (isEdit) within the subscribe callback of an event emitter in my Angular application.
Context:
I have a CreateComponent responsible for adding or editing mobiles.
The isEdit property (boolean) is used to control the component's state (create vs. edit).
A MobileService emits an event (emitId) containing an ID when a mobile needs to be edited.
Code Snippet:
TypeScript
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  isEdit = false;
  mobileId: any;

  constructor(private service: MobileService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.emitId.subscribe((id: any) => {
      console.log('Received ID:', id);
      this.isEdit = true; // Trying to set isEdit to true
      console.log('isEdit value (after setting):', this.isEdit); // Optional for debugging
    });
    console.log('Initial isEdit value:', this.isEdit); // Before subscription
  }

  // ... other component logic
}

Expected Behavior:
Upon receiving an ID through the emitId event, isEdit should be set to true to indicate edit mode.
The template should reflect the change in isEdit (potentially showing different content for create vs. edit mode).
Current Behavior:
The console.log statement inside the subscribe callback shows isEdit is set to true after receiving the ID.
However, the template continues to display content as if isEdit is still false.

Can you show your HTML template please ?

Most likely angular change detection is not run in your component after youbset isEdit to true. You can fix it by making isEdit BehaviorSubjectand subscribing to it in template with acync pipe. This way, when its value changes, angular will mark component for change detection.
This should work:
isEdit = new BehaviorSubject(false);

...
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.emitId.subscribe((id: any) => {
      console.log('Received ID:', id);
      this.isEdit.next(true); // Trying to set isEdit to true
      console.log('isEdit value (after setting):', this.isEdit); // Optional for debugging
    });
    console.log('Initial isEdit value:', this.isEdit.value); // Before subscription
  }

And then in template use "isEdit | async" with async pipe to subscribe to BehaviorSubject.
If you use angular 16+, you can use signal indstead of BehaviorSubject.
Another solution could be injecting changeDetectionRef to component and runing .detectChanges() method in your subscribe, but rxjs approach is generally better for reactive programming

The code looks good, maybe you are experiencing a problem not using unsubscriptions.
If we add unsubscriptions it would look like this:
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    isEdit = false;
    mobileId: any;
    emitIdSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private service: MobileService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.emitIdSubscription = this.service.emitId.subscribe((id: any) => {
            console.log('Received ID:', id);
            this.isEdit = true; // 
            console.log('isEdit value (after setting):', this.isEdit); // 
        });
        console.log('Initial isEdit value:', this.isEdit); //
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks
        this.emitIdSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    // ... other component logic
}

